# "defaultfile" in Fortran OPEN statement not recognized

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I´m compiling a fortran program using GNU fortran 95.

To open a file, the `defaultfile` option is not recognized. Is there a compiler switch to allow the use of this option?

The code has plenty of `OPEN` statements with this option, and I'm looking for a workaround without removing the option.
`OPEN(10,DEFAULTFILE="/DESIRED/PATH/",FILE="MYFILE"...)`

Comment: DEFAULTFILE is not standard but an extension offered by some compilers. I don't know what you are trying to do, but a quick google shows up http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/odl/axplp/progtool/for9590v82/forti64lrm_052.html and http://earth.uni-muenster.de/~joergs/doc/f90/unix-um/dfum_030.html

Comment: Thank you, francescalus, for the links.  I took a solution stated in the second link: just concatenate DEFAULTFILE/FILE and remove the DEFAULTFILE option. Best regards.